# how to disable wordpress autolink plugin in wordpress editor?

Tags: php, wordpress

hi how we can disable tinymce auto link plugin (function) in wordpress editor. when i paste links in wordpress editor, wordpress makes auto link on pasting. how can we disable this function .

i have google it and found its because of tinymce auto plugin

`

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: 'autolink'
});
```

`
but i dont know how we can disable it

Comment: Please don't tag with unrelated tags.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific plugin to disable WordPress autolinks, but you can disable the feature by going to your user profile and unchecking the box next to "Automatically turn text into links."

Comment: i have checked but there is no such option in user profile , please can you give me screenshot where this box is?